# Combining two .mat file into one

Tags: matlab

I want to combine two .mat files into one in Matlab. One file contents 1x776 cells and 1x1 struct another one contents 1x277 cells and 1x1 struct. I want to bind this two files in one and keep the information in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply clear the MATLAB workspace. Load both of your `.mat` files and then save the MATLAB workspace to a new file.

```
>> clear all
>> load('1.mat');
>> load('2.mat');
>> save('combined.mat');
```

Alternatively you could load the two `.mat` files and explicitly pass the variables you want to save into `save` doing away with the need for `clear all`

```
>> load('1.mat');
>> load('2.mat');
>> save('combined.mat', 'cells1', 'struct1', 'cells2', 'struct2');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its only takes last files information and giving me 1x277 cells and 1x1 struct where I need 1x1043 cells and 1x1 struct

Comment: That's not combining 2 `.mat` files into 1. Its combining 2 variables into 1 for different types.